# fixed url scraping(Selenium)

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

hellow! I have a question about 
I wanna **scrape** company names and ticker names in "https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/screener"
So I think Selenium can help my problem. but my code only works on the first page.
I'm sorry for my poor English.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

nasduq_all=[] #ticker+company
nasduq_ticker=[] #ticker lists(홀수)
nasduq_company=[] #company lists(짝수)
dict_nasduq={} #ticker+company

page_url = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/screener'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/kim/Desktop/dgaja/chromedriver')
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
driver.get(page_url)
time.sleep(1)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

#First of all, I'm only trying to go to page 2. :[
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/main/div[2]/article/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[5]/button[2]").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(10)
ticker = soup.find("tbody", {"nasdaq-screener__table-body"}).find_all('a')
for i in ticker: #text
    name=i.text
    nasduq_all.append(name)
print(nasduq_all)
```

Comment: So you want to scarp data from each page right. For example, after done in page 1, you go to page 2 then page 3 etc.

Comment: you may able to use the api behind the download csv file. this url gives you a json object with all the data in the table. https://api.nasdaq.com/api/screener/stocks?tableonly=true&limit=25&offset=0&download=true

Comment: the next page is a button. so you need selenium to find the button and press it  <button class="pagination__next" aria-label="click to go to the next page"></button>

Comment: @ Jonathan Leon, how did you know that specific website offers API access?  I thought of that too.  I didn't see anything obvious on the site that suggests it has an API endpoint.  I'm curious to know how you knew that.